# Django Channels Daphne uvicorn

Tags: django, django-channels, daphne, uvicorn

I wrote Django Channels for practice.

Use Daphne

`daphne project.asgi:application`

Everything works well.

Use uvicorn

`uvicorn project.asgi:application`

Error on the page

```
(index):16 WebSocket connection to'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/123/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I don't know where I went wrong.

I follow the official use

python -m pip install uvicorn gunicorn

`gunicorn project.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`

Error on the page

```
(index):16 WebSocket connection to'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/123/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Please help me where I need to improve, thank you.

Comment: Django Channel is generally works well with Daphne. do you have any requirement to use uvicorn?

Comment: I just want to know if uvicorn can be used with Django Channel, but uvicorn is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use websockets, you need to install uvicorn[standard]:

```
pip install uvicorn[standard]
```

See also https://www.uvicorn.org/#quickstart